# Como usar setCaretPosition em JFormattedTextField?

Tags: java, swing

Estou com problema pra "setar" o cursor no começo do campo, usando o **setCaretPosition(0);** nos campos TextField, ele funciona corretamente, porém, em qualquer campo com mascara (do tipo JFormattedTextField), ele não funciona.

Alguém sabe me dizer o porque ?

Comment: Não funciona como?

Comment: Ele não seta o cursor no começo do campo, no caso na posição 0.

Comment: E seta pra algum lugar? Dá algum erro? Ou simplesmente não faz nada?

Comment: Ele não dá erro. Simplesmente não faz o que deveria, quando se usa  setCaretPosition(0);  ele deve setar o cursor no começo do campo, quando ele ganha focu. E nos meus campos com mascara, ele não faz isso, se vc clicar no campo o cursor fica onde você clicou.

Comment: Acho que você precisa setar um Document para que o cursor sempre inicie no começo.

Comment: Poderia por favor postar um [MVCE](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrando o problema? Não consegui reproduzir aqui (Java 8, no openSuse).

Comment: @diegofm so fazer um extends de PlainDocument resolve ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2202073/5524514